# Call series of Java static methods from Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Let's say I have come across a class with several static setter methods that I'd like to call in a row. The functionality I'm looking for is similar to that provided by doto, except that it must work on a class instead of an object:

```
(doto MyClass
      (setA "a")
      (setB "b"))
```

Unfortunately, when I try this, I get `RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: setA`. Is there a special `doto` macro for classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will leave this question open, since I'm hoping there's a better answer, but here's my home-grown macro to solve this problem:

```
(defmacro doto-class
  "Calls a series of static methods on a class"
  [klass & forms]
  (cons 'do
        (for [f forms]
          `(. ~klass ~f))))
```

which expands the example:

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(doto-class MyClass
              (setA "a")
              (setB "b")))
```

to

```
(do (. MyClass (setA "a"))
    (. MyClass (setB "b")))
```

Comment: My brains fried from work, but I couldn't come up with anything, and the macro I wrote basically ended up looking like yours. I suspect this is such a rare use case that it wasn't considered. I don't think I've ever needed to sequence calls to a static method.

Answer (score 1):

How do you call a static Java method from Clojure? Like this ...

**(Classname/staticMethod args*)**

For example,

```
> (System/getProperty "java.vm.version")

=> "25.141-b15"
```

We want a macro, say `doto-static`, that re-arranges this from `(doto-static System (getProperty "java.vm.version"))`, and also allows a chain of calls.

Such a macro is ...

```
(defmacro doto-static [class-symbol & calls]
  (let [qualify (fn [method-symbol] (->> method-symbol
                                    (name)
                                    (str (name class-symbol) \/)
                                  (symbol)))
        elaborate (fn [[method-symbol & arg-exprs]]
                      (cons (qualify method-symbol) arg-exprs))]
          (cons 'do (map elaborate calls))))
```

For example,

```
> (doto-static System (getProperty "java.vm.version") (getProperty "java.vm.version"))

=> "25.141-b15"
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you know if this macro provides benefits over the naive solution I posted earlier? If so, that'd make a great addition to this answer.

Comment: @user12341234 Yours is cleaner. The only advantage this possesses is to conform to the [preferred syntax for static calls to Java](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#dot). I hadn't got the point of your answer, or I wouldn't have posted this one.